# How to create a Macro that can copy an item one by one sequencially?

Tags: vba, excel, copy, messagebox

I want to copy items one by one by click the macro button, and message box will be the break for each item. Until the Macro read #Value!, It stops copying.

Example:

```
  A 

  B

  C

  D

 #Value!
```

I have created a VBA like this:

```
  Sub Copylineitems()
  Dim i As Integer

   Do

    Sheets("Capital Line Items").Range(Cells(i + 2, 11), Cells(i + 2, 13)).Copy

     MsgBox "copy"

      i = 1 + i


        Loop While Range("K" & (i + 3)) = "#VALUE!"


           End Sub
```

However, this coding is not working.

Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 0):

This sub may work for you. Try following sub....

```
Sub CopyItems()
Dim LastUsedCell As Long
    LastUsedCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & LastUsedCell)
        If IsError(cel.Value) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox cel.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just few adjustment to your code and code from @harun24hr..

```
 Sub Copylineitems()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Do
        Range(Cells(i + 2, 11), Cells(i + 2, 13)).Copy
        MsgBox "copy"
        i = 1 + i
    Loop While Not IsError(Cells(i + 2, 11).Value)

End Sub
```